# How to implement casting for my own class in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, casting

I made a class in AS3 for representing complex numbers. It does not inherit anything. How can I enable casting from e.g. Numbers? I.e. I want this:

```
5 as Complex
```

to be the same as this:

```
new Complex(5);
```

is there a magic cast() function I can put in my class?

Answer (score 3):

Afraid not. `Number` is an unrelated type to your `Complex` class. All you will receive is a:

```
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Number to an unrelated type Complex
```

The only thing I can think of would be to do something like:

```
asComplex(5);

public function asComplex(num:Number):Complex
{
    return new Complex(num);
}
```

but not sure there is much point in that.